# Is it really so difficult to draw smooth lines in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, drawing

I been trying for a while to draw smooth lines in Unity but with Line Renderer I obtained only jagged lines with the corners not rounded, in particular when the angle of curvature is really small  . I incresed the value of antialiasing in quality settings and tried different materials but nothing changed. I also tried to instantiate a sphere every time the mouse move but it creates some gaps between the various spheres, in particular when the mouse go fast. I know there is a plugin called Vectrosity for this but there is a way to achieve this whitout it?

Comment: You probably want a custom material for the line renderer, one that puts a small edge of alpha along the edges.  The hard corners is tougher to fix, as it requires backtracking and inserting additional segments.  Also, your question doesn't follow the [Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) format of SO

Comment: Thank you! Indeed I thought to instantiate a segment where the line renderer curves but I don't know how to find the point where the curves is. And about the material for adding alpha do you mean to add a transparent edges around the material ? I also noticed that when I draw the lines fast the width of the line seems to decrease, is that normal?

Comment: It's been a while since I poked at the Line Renderer, and it has some weird behaviors by default.  So it might be getting smaller *or* it might be that the quad is twisting from "vertical" to "horizontal" and camera angle only makes it *look* like its getting narrower.  And yes, I meant a transparent edge around the material.

Comment: I'm a beginner in Unity and seems strange that it doesn't have a good class for drawing paths with mouse/fingers, anyway thank you for your tips I will try them!

Comment: As a beginner I'd look at a problem like this and think "man, in like six months I could solve this" and just live with it for now.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> I obtained only jagged lines with the corners not rounded, in
>   particular when the angle of curvature is really small .

This was a problem in *Unity 5.4* and below. This problem has been fixed in *Unity 5.5* and above after `LineRenderer` was completely re-designed.

All you have to do is update to *Unity 5.5* or version above and this problem should go away.

There is a new variable called `LineRenderer.numCornerVertices`. You can use that to set how smooth you want the line to be. The value of *5* seems fine for this.

There is also another new variable called `LineRenderer.numCapVertices` that can be used to set how smooth the *end* of the line should be.

This is a screenshot that demonstrate between *5.4* and *5.5* the changes:

[image]

Comment: The lines are still jaggy if zoom in your left(5.5) image, why is it like that? Even in `Unity 2017`, same jaggy. Not fine and smooth as the original `Graphic API` of `iOS`, any way to approve this in Unity?

Comment: Sorry for making you angry, hope I can cancel the downvote.

Comment: Not angry. If you want help from another user then downvote their answer before their response, how do you expect them to help? I mean that's fine if the answer doesn't make sense at-all or is poor. This is your decision and you shouldn't have to remove the downvote. I actually **don't** want you to remove it. You have the right to downvote any question/answer. Happy coding!

Comment: This answer not working for me, situation remain as it in - Unity 2017 : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47922491/line-renderer-pixelated-layout-unity

Comment: There are 3 answers in this. You can try the other ones(jpgm's answer). If not working then **make your own**. See Iggy's answer for how to do so. If you can't make your own from that answer then buy a plugin from the assetstore.

Answer (score 33):

You can get some good results by generating a mesh from a set of points.

The algorithm for it is as follows:

1. You have a set of points, could be generated with bezier curve.

[image]

2. For each point, take a directional vector to the next point `v = (p2 - p1)` *(marked in blue)*. Then rotate that vector by 90 degrees `normal = v.y, -v.x` *marked in red*.

[image]

3. This illustrates that we will use each normal from the point position. You can now multiply this vector in both directions by the desired width of the line.

[image]

4. Create the vertices at those positions.

[image]

5. Add indices to form triangles. It will be something like `[i, w/2 + i, w/2 + i + 1]` where `i` is the current index, and `w` is the total number of vertices.

[image]

6. Create the other triangles. Again something like `[i, w/2 * i + 1, i + 1]`

[image]

7. And the final result. You can add more points to make the line smoother.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to @Iggy 's inspiration and tutorials on catlikecoding.com (where the spline code I'm using comes from), I created a component that will create a mesh based on a spline given a width and sample frequency. Higher sample frequency = smoother curve of course.

```
using UnityEngine;

[ExecuteInEditMode]
[RequireComponent(typeof(MeshFilter), typeof(MeshRenderer), typeof(BezierSpline))]
public class SplineMesh : MonoBehaviour {

  [Range(1, 20)]
  public int sampleFrequency = 5;

  [Range(0, 5f)]
  public float lineWidth = 0.3f;

  BezierSpline spline;
  Mesh mesh;

  private void Awake () {
    spline = GetComponent<BezierSpline>();
    mesh = GetComponent<Mesh>();
  }

  /*
  void Update()
  {
    for(int i = 0; i <= sampleFrequency; i++){
      float interval = i / (float)sampleFrequency;

      var point = spline.GetPoint(interval);
      var direction = spline.GetDirection(interval);

      var perpendicularLeftVec = PerpendicularLeft(direction) * lineWidth;
      var perpendicularRightVec = PerpendicularRight(direction) * lineWidth;

      Debug.DrawLine(point, point + (Vector3)perpendicularLeftVec, Color.magenta, 0.5f, false);
      Debug.DrawLine(point, point + (Vector3)perpendicularRightVec, Color.cyan, 0.5f, false);
    }
  }
  */

    Vector2 PerpendicularRight(Vector2 orig){
        var vec = new Vector2(orig.y, -orig.x);
        vec.Normalize();
        return vec;
    }
    Vector2 PerpendicularLeft(Vector2 orig){
        var vec = new Vector2(orig.y, -orig.x);
        vec.Normalize();
        return vec * -1;
    }

  private Vector3[] vertices;

  public void GenerateMesh(){
    vertices = new Vector3[(sampleFrequency + 1) * 2];

    //iterate over our samples adding two vertices for each one
    for(int s = 0, i = 0; s <= sampleFrequency; s++, i += 2){
      float interval = s / (float)sampleFrequency;

      //get point along spline, and translate to local coords from world
      var point = transform.InverseTransformPoint(spline.GetPoint(interval));
      var direction = spline.GetDirection(interval);

      var perpendicularLeftVec = PerpendicularLeft(direction) * lineWidth;
      var perpendicularRightVec = PerpendicularRight(direction) * lineWidth;
      // var perpendicularVec = turnLeft ? PerpendicularLeft(diffVector) : PerpendicularRight(diffVector);

      vertices[i] = point + (Vector3)perpendicularLeftVec;
      vertices[i + 1] = point + (Vector3)perpendicularRightVec;
    }

    GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh = mesh = new Mesh();
    mesh.name = "Spline Mesh";

    mesh.vertices = vertices;

    //now figure out our triangles
    int [] triangles = new int[sampleFrequency * 6];
    for(int s = 0, ti = 0, vi = 0; s < sampleFrequency; s++, ti += 6, vi += 2){
      //first tri
      triangles[ti] = vi;
      triangles[ti + 1] = vi + 3;
      triangles[ti + 2] = vi + 1;
      //second matching tri
      triangles[ti + 3] = vi;
      triangles[ti + 4] = vi + 2;
      triangles[ti + 5] = vi + 3;
    }

    mesh.triangles = triangles;
    mesh.RecalculateNormals();

    Debug.Log("Generated Spline Mesh");
  }


}
```

Comment: Instead of commenting out only the contents of `Update`, you should comment out the whole `Update` method to avoid an unnecessary function call slowing things down.

Comment: @Ruzihm as far as I know this is not enough. You specifically have to set the behaviours .enabled to false to not have any calls to Update()

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue with Unity 2017.2. I tried changing my AA settings to max to get rid of line render jaggies. Didn't work and it was frustrating.

My solution was resolving the problem that MSAA was turned off on the camera because rendering was deferred. The camera has a setting for "use graphics settings" which should have never messed up in the first place, but I'm a beginner - I don't know much. I changed the setting to "forward" and my jaggies disappeared into the mist.

If I was more industrious, I would post before and after images.

Comment: I have been trying to find the answer to this for a while and this was the fix. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

I finally got this working thanks to @Iggy's excellent answer.

Create a new Image on your canvas, delete the Image script and replace it with UICubicBezier.

[image]

To give:

[image]

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

[ExecuteInEditMode]
public class UiCubicBezier : MaskableGraphic
{
    public float thickness = 2;

    public int anchors = 20;

    protected override void OnPopulateMesh(VertexHelper vh)
    {
        // draws a cubic bezier curve from the lower left hand corner (start)
        // to the upper right hand corner (end).
        vh.Clear();

        var rt = this.rectTransform;
        var rect = rt.rect;

        var start = new Vector2(-rect.width / 2, -rect.height / 2);
        var cp1 = new Vector2(-rect.width / 6, -rect.height / 2);
        var cp2 = new Vector2(rect.width / 6, rect.height / 2);
        var end = new Vector2(rect.width / 2, rect.height / 2);
        var data = new BezierData(start, cp1, cp2, end);

        // all you need to know is that data.GetPoint generates a sequence of points
        // between the start and end points.
        var points = new Vector2[this.anchors];
        for (var anchor = 0; anchor < points.Length; anchor++)
        {
            var t = (float)anchor / this.anchors;
            points[anchor] = data.GetPoint(t);
        }

        // because the normals are at the mid-points between vertexes the start and end
        // points don't touch the bounding box. to fix this some vertexes are added to
        // the start and end that touch the bounding box.
        this.DrawStartVertexes(vh, start);

        for (var anchor = 0; anchor < points.Length - 1; anchor++)
        {
            this.DrawVertexes(vh, points[anchor], points[anchor + 1]);
        }

        this.DrawEndVertexes(vh, end);

        for (var v = 0; v + 2 < vh.currentVertCount; v += 2)
        {
            vh.AddTriangle(v, v + 1, v + 2);
        }

        for (var v = 0; v + 3 < vh.currentVertCount; v += 2)
        {
            vh.AddTriangle(v + 1, v + 2, v + 3);
        }
    }

    private void DrawStartVertexes(VertexHelper vh, Vector2 start)
    {
        // d = thickness * \sqrt{2}, so the distance between the vertexes
        // is equal to the thickness (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle#Right_triangles)
        var d = this.thickness * 0.70710678118f;

        var vertex = UIVertex.simpleVert;
        vertex.color = this.color;

        vertex.position = new Vector2(start.x, start.y + d);
        vh.AddVert(vertex);

        vertex.position = new Vector2(start.x + d, start.y);
        vh.AddVert(vertex);
    }

    private void DrawEndVertexes(VertexHelper vh, Vector2 end)
    {
        // d = thickness * \sqrt{2}, so the distance between the vertexes
        // is equal to the thickness (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle#Right_triangles)
        var d = this.thickness * 0.70710678118f;

        var vertex = UIVertex.simpleVert;
        vertex.color = this.color;

        vertex.position = new Vector2(end.x - d, end.y);
        vh.AddVert(vertex);

        vertex.position = new Vector2(end.x, end.y - d);
        vh.AddVert(vertex);
    }

    private void DrawVertexes(VertexHelper vh, Vector2 start, Vector2 end)
    {
        var v = end - start;
        var mid = start + v / 2; // the mid-point between start and end.
        var perp = Vector2.Perpendicular(v.normalized); // vector of length 1 perpendicular to v.

        var vertex = UIVertex.simpleVert;
        vertex.color = this.color;

        // move half the thickness away from the mid-point.
        vertex.position = mid + (perp * this.thickness / 2); 
        vh.AddVert(vertex);

        // move half the thickness away from the mid-point in the opposite direction.
        vertex.position = mid - (perp * this.thickness / 2);
        vh.AddVert(vertex);
    }

    private struct BezierData
    {
        private readonly Vector2 start;
        private readonly float cx;
        private readonly float bx;
        private readonly float ax;
        private readonly float cy;
        private readonly float by;
        private readonly float ay;

        public BezierData(Vector2 start, Vector2 cp1, Vector2 cp2, Vector2 end)
        {
            // cribbed from here: https://www.codeproject.com/articles/25237/bezier-curves-made-simple

            this.start = start;
            this.cx = 3 * (cp1.x - start.x);
            this.bx = 3 * (cp2.x - cp1.x) - this.cx;
            this.ax = end.x - start.x - this.cx - this.bx;

            this.cy = 3 * (cp1.y - start.y);
            this.by = 3 * (cp2.y - cp1.y) - this.cy;
            this.ay = end.y - start.y - this.cy - this.by;
        }

        public Vector2 GetPoint(float t)
        {
            var tSquared = t * t;
            var tCubed = tSquared * t;

            return new Vector2(
                (this.ax * tCubed) + (this.bx * tSquared) + (this.cx * t) + this.start.x,
                (this.ay * tCubed) + (this.by * tSquared) + (this.cy * t) + this.start.y);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

TLDR:
Consider using [Shapes](https://acegikmo.com/shapes/) by [Freya Holmér](https://twitter.com/FreyaHolmer/)

Disclaimer: I haven't tried it myself yet, but the results look amazing.

In the past I have created custom solutions where I'd create custom meshes (similar to other solutions described here), vertex shader that offset the verts in screen space and fragment shader with alpha blending to achieve nice AA. I never found the time to create a proper, re-usable package of it, but Freya's solution seem to be much more advanced.

If I were to need something like this again, I'd check out her library first.